# Old sci-fi book where a man is transported to another world, and meets woman with green skin. Involves black floating transport?

Tags: story-identification, books

Not much to go on but I've kept looking for years, hope someone can help.

About 25 years ago I bought a second-hand book from a camp site shop in the UK. It was about a man transported to an alien planet/alternate dimension, possibly from a building site? He finds a green woman and a form of transport that is a floating black object, possibly a cube. I remember the cover looking quite old.

The only further thing I can think of is that I think the cover had a blonde man on it with a silly long bowl cut (think He-Man) and a green woman with a black bob. I bought the book early 90s and I think it was probably 60's or 70's. It was in English. I've racked my brain and searched Google for years but never got anywhere. I don't know why I keep searching as I clearly can't remember the book well!

Comment: Please look through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and try to add any more info you can think of. This is currently very little to go on.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response and sorry for the lack of detail. The only further thing I can think of is that I think the cover had a blonde man on it with a silly long bowl cut (think heman) and a green woman with a black bob. I bought the book early 90s and I think it was probably 60's or 70's. It was in English. I've racked my brain and searched Google for years but never got anywhere. I don't know why I keep searching as I clearly can't remember the book well! Haha

Answer (score 4):

This "green woman" memory might possibly be from *Chaining the Lady*, the second book of the Cluster series by Piers Anthony.

There was no green woman in the book itself, but there was one on at least [one version of the cover](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15519.Chaining_the_Lady).

In this book, Melody of Mintaka is chosen to have her "aura" transferred to another "sphere" to pass along the technology of "Transfer" -- this mind transference itself.  She is chosen because her aura is exceptionally strong (as was the case for Flint in the first book); this gives her a better chance to survive the slow fading of her aura long enough to pass along the knowledge and perhaps even be transferred back to her own body.

The *first* book, however, *Cluster*, featured Flint, a stone age artisan (named for his working material), who was chosen for the same task, but was initially human.  He did encounter a flying machine at one point that was basically a box in which he put his feet.

I suspect you might have read an omnibus edition with all three of the original trilogy in a single volume, and a cover taken from the second book.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a fast and comprehensive answer! I'm going to go and have a proper look at these books now. Sometimes I wonder if I'm remembering it correctly at all as this sounds intensely familiar!

Comment: Sadly I don't think it was this series, although, it looks good so I'll give it a read! Thank you so much for your help and information.

Comment: Okay, doesn't match additional information you added in comments.  Very 1980s, though.  Also read the Tarot trilogy by the same author; they're connected (and one or both might be more than three books since I read them as they came out; he's admitted he can't count to three).